# web app links in apps script not working properly after deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I just notice and it seems it is happening in all of my projects. My web apps work fine in test deployment, but when I do a new deployment and setup for any user and I share the links, it loads with broken links, images does not load and in one of my web apps the links in the navigation bar does not work. All of them take me to a page that it says hello. It seems that it does not update from previous test deployments.

this is the last version
[image]

with my account it loads perfectly fine
[image]

with other google account
[image]

does anyone know why this happen? Can it be fixed?

Comment: How can what be fixed?

Comment: Have you ever tried to use dataURI to store the image within the url?